# Shared Partial View ActionResult Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am trying to return the parent View when I call an ActionResult from within a Partial View.  If I know the parent view I can just type in return View("Index");, but I can't because their could be multiple parent views as this partial view is shared...  So how do I return the correct parent View in the ActionResult?

This seems so simple, but it has me stumped...

Update.  Here is the Partial View:

```
@model Website.Models.PostModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, 2, 50, null)
<br /><br />
<div class="ui-widget">
    Notes: @Html.TextBox("Notes", "", new { @class = "ui-autocomplete-input" })
</div>
<br />
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</p>
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using `@{Html.RenderAction("Action");}` in your view to call

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Action()
{
    var model = context.Data.Where(x => x);

    return PartialView("PartialView", model);
}
```

if so, then you could specify your routeValues as well.
In your view you would call

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Action", new {viewName = "parentView"});}
```

and in you controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Action(string viewName)
{
    var model = context.Data.Where(x => x);

    if (model == null) return View(viewName);

    return PartialView("PartialView", model);
}
```

Comment: I am using HTML.BeginForm for my submit button.  Do I need to pass the parent's model to the partial view?

Comment: Finally figured it out.  Had to pass the view name to the partial render like you pointed out.  Thanks for the help!